# How to merge branches on github.com without doing pull request?

Tags: github

It looks like GitHub only allows merging of branches by making a pull request **and then** merging.

Is there a way to merge `mobile` into `main` in a single step **without cloning locally?**

I only see this button, which creates a pull request that needs to be merged in a second step:

[image: Compare, review, create a pull request]

Comment: There's no way without using a pull request. Why avoid both PR and command line?

Comment: Why cant you merge from command line?

Comment: It should only take time to pull once unless they are changing large binaries. If they *are* changing large binaries on any kind of regular basis, you need to really evaluate your usage of git. It's not designed for that and it will perform terribly. You should consider some other way to manage binaries

Comment: See http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148003/83848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GitHub Docs' [GraphQL API Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) to run a [`mergeBranch` mutation](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#mergebranch):

```gql
mutation {
  mergeBranch(
    input: {
      repositoryId: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcwNzI="
      base: "master"
      head: "cool_feature"
      commitMessage: "Shipped cool_feature!"
    }
  ) {
    clientMutationId
    mergeCommit {
      oid
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You can look up your repository's `id` by using the [`repository`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/queries#repository) query to search by `owner` and `name`.

```gql
{
  repository(owner: "my-name", name: "my-repo") {
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Clever! This is the only solution that works "on GitHub.com" exactly as the question specifies. The only issue is that it might not work with restrictive organizations as the API Explorer is an "external" OAuth App.

Comment: Teamwork for the win! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 30):

Github does not provide such a mechanism - and by following best practices, it doesn't make sense for them to provide such a feature.

The steps are to Merge it on your machine, then Push:

```
git merge mobile
git push
```

Pull requests are really only for repositories you don't control, and/or some code review process.

Per comments on the question, if this isn't convenient for you, very likely it is a sign of going against best practices, hindering your ability to work correctly.

Comment: then the answer is simply: you can't.

Comment: @bfred.it You could technically say that git is accessing github.com for you.

Comment: **It's possible** via GraphQL Explorer now, see the accepted answer.

Comment: This solved my problem. My use case is: I'm working on a project on my own but I still want to use git and branching for its added benefits. But I don't want all the hassle of creating a pull request after I've pushed a branch to the remote repo (and it doesn't make sense, since I'll be the one approving it). So just merging locally and then pushing makes much more sense.

Answer (score 14):

Github does not provide this functionality via the web UI at this point.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do it on the website itself, but you can do it via the [Branches API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branches#merge-a-branch), without cloning locally:

```bash
curl \
  --header "Authorization: token $TOKEN" \
  --data '{"base":"master","head":"develop","commit_message":"YOOOO"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/merges
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub's [desktop app](https://desktop.github.com/) lets you do this with the menu item `Branch` → `Merge Into Current Branch...`. Presumably it's just doing a `git merge` under the hood as in [Eevee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276423/2786201), but it's nice and easy. :)

Comment: I specified _on github.com_. The desktop app requires you to clone the repo.